# What visa do I need to apply for going to Spain?

Tags: visas, schengen, spain, filipino-citizens, weddings

I would like to ask what Visa do I need to apply, cause my fiance is a British National, and I am a Filipina, we plan to get married here in Philippines or in Spain. My fiance has his Residencia in Spain that's why he want us to live in Spain after we get married. Will I be able to get a Marriage Visa to Spain? or a Spouse Visa after we get married? if ever, what are the requirements needed?

Comment: What do you mean by "here": `we plan to get married here`?

Comment: I mean we plan to get married here in Philippines or Spain.